# Strange behavior when configuring iptables over SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, iptables

I am trying to apply [these](http://pastebin.com/e5ppGxcS) firewall rules over SSH. When I run the script with ./script.sh, the terminal will hang and I am forced to quit using `~ . Enter`. The rules are applied, but my SSH connection is dropped and my terminal hangs. However, when I do `bash -x ./script.sh`, it runs the script while outputting debug information and doesn't interrupt my session.

My firewall rules are simple. Allow incoming/outgoing SSH and allow outgoing DNS and HTTP/S for updates.

This behavior was witnessed on Red Hat, Debian, and Ubuntu machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I consider you are running the scripts on a ssh session established on default port 22

then please replace the ssh rules

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m limit --limit 5/minute --limit-burst 15 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

for a less restrictive set i.e.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

once you get it working you can add to these now simpler rules the more restrictive parameters one at the time.

please consider if your input rule includes

```
--state NEW
```

only new ssh connections will be accepted; already established will not.

Comment: That did the trick. How should I go about preserving NEW/ESTABLISHED in there without dropping the connection?

Comment: my approach is not limiting output; all the traffic originated from the protected device is allowed. Next I protect input allowing NEW and ESTABLISHED for a protocol like  SHH and adding RELATED for a protocol like i.e. FTP

Comment: I've managed to isolate the problem. It was with the OUTPUT rule preventing re-establishment of the connection. I decided to remove the state option from it and problem solved. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Move this rule to the top and test again:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Didn't make a difference.